# AngularJs ng-controller overrides

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js

I am newbie with AngularJS, I really need some help here.

I have [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/muzicupadi/edit?html,output) working example that displays two charts with different data.

For each chart I have different ng-controller. By issue is my select dropdown only works with `<div   ng-controller="first">` chart.

My goals is to update both charts with select dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you check clearly,
The **$scope.filterOptions** which is used in dropdown is defined in **first** controller. It is available in **second** because it is nested controller

`<select ng-model="selectedyear" ng-change="sampleDropDown()">
  <option ng-repeat="year in`**filterOptions.stores**`|  unique: 'year'">
    {{ year.year }}
  </option>
 </select>`

Comment: you're right. There is bad coding, because of my lack of knowledge. I needed to make same filter for both charts > created from data avaliable in two different controller. And just take of **filterOptions.stores** any suggestion here ? Thanks

Comment: If you mean by using same data in 2 different controllers, you can use one of the key angular features, **service/factory**

Comment: Yes. Never made custom **service/factory** but I will give try, thank you so much for helps. I hope its not too difficult.

Comment: Thanks, once I get it working, I will surely accept your answer. Thank you